# xCode Autolayout stuck in iPhone 4 Mode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm working on an iPhone app using Swift. For some reason, the app doesn't fill the entire screen of the device. For example, I'm testing the app on an iPhone 5S, and it's the height of an iPhone 4. Why is this? I haven't changed any settings in the storyboard for auto layout just yet. Here are my settings for the simulated metrics.

[image]

Comment: Have you e balde SizeClasses?

Comment: I haven't. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than you need but you'll find your answer:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial

B.R

Comment: Annother powerful tutorial for you: http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/
Have fun!